# How to make a single variable perform as a script

Tags: perl

I've been using this module to write simple scripts to log into a server and perform a single command.

```
use Net::SSH qw(sshopen2);
use strict;

my $user = "username";
my $host = "hostname";
my $cmd = "command";

sshopen2("$user\@$host", *READER, *WRITER, "$cmd") || die "ssh: $!";

while (<READER>) {
    chomp();
    print "$_\n";
}

close(READER);
close(WRITER);
```

But I need the $cmd variable to perform this operation below.

```
my $dir = "/srv/archive/$date";
my $time = `date`;

open my $LOG, '>>', '/srv/archive/test.log';

if ( ! -e $dir )

{
my $to = 'xxxxx@xxxxx.com';
my $from = 'node0@example.com';
my $subject = '**DROP FILE TEST ALERT**';
my $message = "Please check if the $date directory exists";

open(MAIL, "|/usr/sbin/sendmail -t");

# Email Header
print MAIL "To: $to\n";
print MAIL "From: $from\n";
print MAIL "Subject: $subject\n\n";
# # Email Body
print MAIL $message;
close(MAIL);
print "Email Sent Successfully\n"    ;
print $LOG "$time (Bad)";    

}

else

{

print "The directory exists!\n";
print $LOG "$time (Good)\n";

}
```

The reason why I'm using this is because I am not allowed to execute a script inside the server. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Manually printing headers to `sendmail` is no longer a good way to send email. [Modern email contains multiple, complicated guards against spammers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-spam_techniques#Automated_techniques_for_email_administrators). Most mail servers and clients will reject your mail as spam.

There's no reason the email has to be sent on the remote server.  Instead, send the mail via a normal SMTP connection.  Consider using [Email::Sender](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Sender) instead.

If you absolutely *must* send the mail from the remote server, write a script to do it (also using Email::Sender) and invoke that script.